# Rails 2.3.5 - Error installing mysql: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried with gem install mysql and gem list, so I was able to see mysql gem in that list, but when I restarted the server it gives me following error

The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- mysql (MissingSourceFile)

I then tried gem install mysql2
It installs mysql but gives the same error when I start the server.. Please help!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what gems your project includes. In Rails 2.2, you did this in the environment config files. Change this line in your `environment.rb`:

```
  config.gem 'mysql'
```

To this:

```
  config.gem 'mysql2'
```